# Error while running emulator in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

When I am trying to start android virtual device in eclipse I am getting the error as `Parsing Data for android-26 failed Unsupported major.minor version 52.0.`
I had tried by installing all `SDK` Tools even though I am getting same error. I searched for the error in internet but the answers are for another version and error code is also different. Can anyone please clarify doubt.

Comment: Basically you're using two versions of java, most likely java 7 and java 8. Check your installed java version and the one you're using to compile

Comment: It seems your eclipse doesn't support JAVA-8.
Secondly, Google support for Eclipse is deprecated due to which ADT plugin will not be updated.